# Google indexes my sitemap as HTML

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I cannot find the solution for this, I have also asked on Google Forums but they haven't solved the problem.

As my webpage changes everyday, I am generating a dynamic sitemap with PHP. The process I have followed for this:

1.- Create a file named `sitemap.php` with this code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
echo "<urlset xmlns='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'
        xmlns:news='http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9'>";

    require 'admin/config.php';
    require 'funciones.php';

    try {
        $conexion = new PDO($bd_config['dbname'], $bd_config['usuario'], $bd_config['password'] );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        header ('Location: error.php');
        echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
        die();
    }

//CODE 

echo "</urlset>\n";

?>
```

2.- In the `.htaccess` file I insert this code:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

3.- And finally, in `robots.txt` file this other code:

```
Sitemap: http://www.laxtore.com/sitemap.php
```

But whenever I upload the file in Google, it recognizes it as an HTML file, even if I go to the file directory, the XML is generating correctly. Here you can check it: http://www.laxtore.com/sitemap.php

I cannot share an image yet due to the reputation (I´m new here).

¿Is there a way to solve this? I have also tried to use an xml generated online, and even with that file I receive the same error

**EDIT:**

Google support has told me that I cannot use this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.org/business/article55.html</loc>
    <news:news>
      <news:publication>
        <news:name>The Example Times</news:name>
        <news:language>en</news:language>
      </news:publication>
      <news:genres>PressRelease, Blog</news:genres>
      <news:publication_date>2008-12-23</news:publication_date>
      <news:title>Companies A, B in Merger Talks</news:title>
      <news:keywords>business, merger, acquisition, A, B</news:keywords>
      <news:stock_tickers>NASDAQ:A, NASDAQ:B</news:stock_tickers>
    </news:news>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

But is the one they put as example on its site: https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/74288?hl=es

**EDIT 2:**

After trying modifying that structure and using just:

```
echo "<url>\n";
          echo "<loc>http://www.laXtore.com/noticia/" . $articulo['ID'] . "/" . limpia_url($articulo['titulo']) . "/</loc>\n";
          echo "<changefreq>daily</changefreq>\n";
          echo "<priority>1</priority>\n";
        echo "</url>\n";
```

I keep having the same problem. I am thinking that it could be due to `www.` redirect or whatever. In Google Webmaster Tool when I send the sitemap, the URL is `http://laxtore.com/sitemap.php`, but to access to the sitemap I have to introduce `http://www.laxtore.com/sitemap.php`, otherwise nothing is charged.

Answer (score 0):

just try to send Google your XML-Sitemap, I think that Google don´t recognize Sitemaps as XML if they don´t end with .xml. https://www.laxtore.com/sitemap.xml

This structure you tried:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.org/business/article55.html</loc>
    <news:news>
      <news:publication>
        <news:name>The Example Times</news:name>
        <news:language>en</news:language>
      </news:publication>
      <news:genres>PressRelease, Blog</news:genres>
      <news:publication_date>2008-12-23</news:publication_date>
      <news:title>Companies A, B in Merger Talks</news:title>
      <news:keywords>business, merger, acquisition, A, B</news:keywords>
      <news:stock_tickers>NASDAQ:A, NASDAQ:B</news:stock_tickers>
    </news:news>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Is a sitemap for Google news and can only be used by publisher.

Also you shouldhave a www. Search Console Account if you have this as your site URL.